# Как создать (MSVS, native c++) std::unique_ptr или std::shared_ptr на массив объектов, у класса которых нет default ctr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Только не надо объяснять, что vector лучше (Win API с векторами как-то не очень...)

Comment: Корректно вы это не сделаете, потому что получить массив неинициализированных объектов - это результат на троечку, на самом деле. Как минимум потому, что непонятно, как потом такой массив удалять.

Comment: Было бы также неплохо объяснить, что не так у вас с  STL и WinAPI, что там "не очень"

Comment: А в чем проблема с векторами, кстати? Получить указатель на массив через `data()` и никаких проблем...

Comment: Нет, я, видать, не очень удачно тут Win API всуе помянул.
Просто не получается составить синтактически правильную конструкцию для создания умного пойнтера на такой массив.
Попрост говоря, не понимаю, куда пихать аргументы констрактора.

Comment: @gbg typedef struct
 {
  OVERLAPPED oOverlap;
  HANDLE hPipeInst;
  uint8_t chRequest[BUFSIZE];
  DWORD cbRead;
  uint8_t chReply[BUFSIZE];
  DWORD cbToWrite;
  DWORD dwState;
  BOOL fPendingIO;
 } 
 PIPEINST;

Ну вот такую, например, структуру определяет нам Win API на каждый канал pipe'а. И я хочу размер буфера и количество каналов задавать динамически.

Comment: @LionButcher так вы хотите, чтобы у вас был массив идентичных объектов (созданных с одинаковыми параметрами), или разных объектов?

Comment: @gbg Объекты идентичные, просто их параметры определяются в момент создания.

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите использовать умные указатели, для типов, которые должны аллоцироваться и удаляться вызовами WinAPI? Т.е. вопрос как привязать собственную функцию удаления к умным указателям?

```
struct Foo;
Foo* makeFoo();
void destroyFoo(Foo* foo); // Какая-то функция деструкции у вас должна быть.




std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo( makeFoo(),   
                               destroyFoo // Второй аргумент конструктора  - функция деструкции
                             );


struct FooDeleter{ 
   void operator() ( Foo* f ) { destroyFoo(f); }
};
std::unique_ptr<Foo, 
                FooDeleter // Второй аргумент шаблона - deleter_type
 > uniqueFoo( makeFoo() );
```

Comment: new Foo[1000] - не откомпилируется, потому что нет конструктора по умолчанию (так написано в условии задачи)

Comment: Хорошо, проблема заметена под ковер. Следующий вопрос - как деструктор узнает, какие объекты в массиве инициализированы, а какие - еще нет?

Comment: @gbg Это проблема реализации WinAPI. Так ли иначе эта информация должна содержаться в указателе `Foo*`. CloseHandle нормально узнает какой именно тип указателя ему передан, хотя на пользовательской стороне никакой информации о реальном типе недоступно.

Comment: Еще раз. Вы создали массив каких-то объектов, но конструктор ни у одного объекта не вызван (так как его просто нет). Теперь вопрос - как вы будете удалять массив, вы должны всем объектам вызвать функцию-деструктор. Вызов деструктора у неинициализированииого объекта - UB.

Comment: @gbg тут грань между конструктора/деструктора вообще нет и они недоступны пользователю API. Хотя я мог неверно понять автора вопроса.

Comment: Господа, конструктор есть, и деструктор есть, просто конструктор требует аргументы. Куда их писать? (синтаксис нужной конструкции никак уловить не могу.
Harry, спасибо, идея хорошая, вот только data  ведь const, небось, да?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать вектор одинаковых элементов без кучи копирований, следует сделать следующее:

```
std::vector<Foo> vec; 
vec.reserve(cnt);           //выделили память под все
                            //элементы. Конструкторы при этом не нужны
                            //так как элементы НЕ создаются
for(size_t i=0;i!=cnt;++i)
{
    //элементы создаются прямо внутри вектора, лишних 
    //копирований не будет
    //в качестве параметров указываются параметры, которые будут 
    //переданы в конструктор
    vec.emplace_back(ctr_parameter1, ctr_parameter2, etc...);     
}
```